# C# newbie problem with variable types

Tags: c#, integer, double, type-conversion

```
int newWidth = 100;
int newHeight = 100;
double ratio = 0;

if (img1.Width > img1.Height)
{
    ratio = img1.Width / img1.Height;
    newHeight = (int)(newHeight / ratio);
}
else
{
    ratio = img1.Height / img1.Width;
    newWidth = (int)(newWidth / ratio);
}

Image bmp1 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
bmp1.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Photos/Thumbnails/") + photo.PhotoID + ".jpg");
```

I always get Image with both height and width having same values (100)
I am obiously doing something wrong with type conversion?

Comment: What values do `img1.Width` and `img1.Height` have?

Comment: @Präriewolf: I don't get any errors. @Péter Török: Hmm... I'm not pretty sure but I think it's integer because I can declare newWidth = img1.Width with no errors.

Comment: Can you give some examples of image sizes that your are testing?

Comment: width=800 and height=533

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ratio = img1.Width / img1.Height;
```

Width and Height are integers. You will be performing integer math on these values before storing them in your double. In integer math, 150 / 100 is 1. 199 / 100 is 1. 101 / 100 is  1. There are no decimals. After the value has been calculated, *then* it will be stored in your double.

Cast at least one side to double before doing your calculation.

```
ratio = img1.Width / (double)img1.Height;
```

Comment: Hmmm... now I tried to upload new photo with dimensions width=800 and height=533 and thumbnail is newWidth=800 and newHeight=66

Comment: @ile, I don't see where that would happen in your code snippet. Are you setting newWidth = img.Width anywhere that's not visible above? Because you shouldn't. newWidth, from your snippet, should remain 100.

Comment: upvoted this is actually covered in one of the ms press books I went through for my foundation exam, definately need to cast one of the figures (I usually do the divisor) to double to avoid loss of precision.

Comment: Can you step through the code with the debugger and see when the newWidth changes to 800?

Comment: Anthony, you were right! I left newWidth = img.Width below if statement and forgot to remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

```
ratio = img1.Width / (img1.Height * 1.0);
```

To ensure that the value of the result is not truncated due to integer arithmetic.

Comment: Personally, I think casting (ala @Anthony's answer) makes the intent more clear.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the images?  if the width and height are always equal then this would make sense.

```
newWidth = (int)(newWidth / ratio);  // this is newWidth = newWidth / 1 so it doesn't change.
```

Comment: height and width are not the same. I test both horizontal and vertical photos